# Formatting a scope attribute in a custom boost log format function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm using a custom formatting function, and am trying to figure out how to format a scope attribute.  The examples in the boost documentation that I've found are for lambda expression formatters, which I don't know how I would use within my formatter function.  Right now I'm successfully using attributes like the timetamp, but the scope attribute escapes me.

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(scope, "Scope", attributes::named_scope_list)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(timestamp, "TimeStamp", boost::posix_time::ptime)

void formatter(boost::log::record_view const& record, boost::log::formatting_ostream& stream) {
  stream << record[timestamp];
  // stream << record[scope].file_name or something like that
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you retrieve the attribute, it gives you a `named_scope_list`, which as its name suggests is a list of `named_scope`s.  Each `named_scope` is a `struct` containing the file, line, and name of the scope (function name).

Thus, it can be used like so:

```
attributes::named_scope_list scopeList = record[scope].get();
for (attributes::named_scope_list::const_iterator iter = scopeList.begin(); iter != scopeList.end(); ++iter)
{
  stream << iter->line;
}
```